# Customize Apache Ignite Kubernetes Operator to create service of type "ClusterIP" instead of "LoadBalancer"

Tags: ignite, gridgain

We have deployed Apache ignite 2.14 in Kubernetes using [GridGain's Operator](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/installation-guide/operator-0.2.0/overview).

The Operator is creating the service of type "LoadBalancer", when we try to change the type as "ClusterIP" operator is change it back to "LoadBalancer". We are trying to use this in production, so we cannot expose public IP. We need service of type "ClusterIP"

Is there any way to tell the operator to create the service as "ClusterIP" instead of "LoadBalancer" ?

Also is there any way to pass the tolerations & affinity information to operator, so that operator will create the ignite cluster based on that affinity ?

Answer (score 1):

As per [this config](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/installation-guide/operator-0.2.0/operator-configuration#ignite-resource), there is not a setting which could direct the operator to 
 use anything except a LoadBalancer.
You can however, [adjust the settings on your cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cluster-endpoint.html) provider to make the IP not be visible to the outside world.

Comment: In cloud we are already doing that, we are using azure and we made the load balancer as internal. Just want to know is it supported by the operator to deploy the cluster in OnPrem